# Why won't my code write to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, service

I'm writing an app to store texts to an SQL database, but my code throws an exception saying "the variable name @par1 has already been declared", I'm not sure how to get this working and would like some help fixing this if possible please =]

offending code is below

```
 private void SMSGetter()
    {
         try {

                DecodedShortMessage[] messages = Comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, PhoneStorageType.Sim);
                SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*********;Initial Catalog=********;User ID=**********;Password=***********");
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
                com.Connection = Conn;
                Conn.Open();
                foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
                {

                    //com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO SMSArchives(Message,Blacklist) VALUES ('" + message.Data.UserDataText + "', 'Yes')");
                    //com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO SMSArchives(Message,Blacklist) VALUES (@par1,@par2)");
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par1", message.Data.UserDataText);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par2", "Yes");
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                Conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Log(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have a nasty SQL injection attack surface there. It seems odd that you'd use parameters for some but not all inputs.

Comment: The problem is you don't need to add your parameters or redefine your commandtext inside a loop. That should be done once before.

Comment: it throws an exception saying I need to declare the scalar variable @par3

Answer (score 6):

You are using the same command for every iteration, but **adding** parameters each time. Try calling

```
com.Parameters.Clear();
```

at the end of each loop iteration. You could also pre-create the parameters and just set the `.Value` per iteration - probably marginally faster.

Also: fix the SQL injection hole :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void SMSGetter()
{

    Log("Getter Fired");

    //var message = GSM.ReadMessage(4);
    //GSM.ReadMessage(4);
    //TcpClientChannel client = new TcpClientChannel();
    //ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(client, false);
    //string url = "*******";
    //ISmsSender smssender = (ISmsSender)Activator.GetObject(typeof(ISmsSender), url);
           try
        {

            DecodedShortMessage[] messages = Comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, PhoneStorageType.Sim);
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*********;Initial Catalog=********;User ID=**********;Password=***********");
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = Conn;
            Conn.Open();
            com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO SMSArchives(Message,Blacklist) VALUES (@par1,@par2)");
            com.Parameters.Add("@par1");
            com.Parameters.Add("@par2");
            foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
            {
                com.Parameters["@par1"].value = message.Data.UserDataText;
                com.Prepare(); //fix SQL injection :)
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            Conn.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Log(ex.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the parameters at every iteration in foreach. Consider the following:

```
        com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO SMSArchives(Message,Blacklist) VALUES (@par1,@par2)");
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@par1", ""));
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par2", "Yes");
        foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
        {
            command.Parameters["@par1"].Value = message.Data.UserDataText;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```